# Max size of JSON column in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Given this table in a MySQL 5.7 database `mydb`:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stuff` json DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

How would I get the maximum size of the data in the `stuff` column? Not the maximum *possible* size, but the maximum *current* size across all rows in the table. I've tried `SELECT max(JSON_STORAGE_SIZE(stuff)) from foo`, but I get the error `ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION mydb.json_storage_size does not exist`.

Comment: Maybe `length` and `sum`? The `max` function brings back the highest value, not length/size.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an approximate length by querying it as a string:

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(stuff)) FROM foo
```

This may not match the `JSON_STORAGE_SIZE()` though.

The `JSON_STORAGE_SIZE()` function was added in MySQL 5.7.22. If you have an older version, you can't use that function unless you upgrade.

The error you saw indicates that MySQL doesn't know it as a builtin function, so it's trying to execute it as if you had create a stored function by that name.